# Existence on an isomorphic permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism

This was a bonus question on my old homework assignment and so I didn’t receive a solution for this.

Let $G\leq S_m$ and $H\leq S_n$ be permutation groups. Show that there exists a permutation group $K\leq S_{m+n}$ for which $G\times H\cong K$.

I don’t really have a clue on what kind of observations are needed to even get started. I have just tried to see why this would be true for some m,n but I dont have an intuition for what K would look like. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try a simple one: if $G = H  = \langle(12)\rangle$ in $S_2$, what would $G\times H$ look like?

Comment: Hint: there is “room enough” in $S_{m+n}$ to represent $G$ and $H$ as *disjoint* products of cycles. Hence $H$ and $G$ centralize each other and $H \cap G=(1)$. Try a small example.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There is a inclusion $S_n \times S_m  \hookrightarrow{} S_{n+m}$ by defining $\sigma \in S_n$ to act on the first $n$ elements of $\{1, \dots, m+n\}$ and $\tau \in S_m$ to act on the last $m$ elements.